# How can I avoid duplicating logic in Control Flow

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have a package which looks as follows:

[image: SSIS]

Notice the two areas which I have marked with a red rectangle: they are identical in every way. Can I make changes to the package so I can avoid this duplication? It seems to me I cannot move them to a Data Flow Task since loops and File System Task do not exists there.

Comment: Don't mean to be flippant, but couldn't you just put that logic in another package and use an Execute Package Task. (given parameters, that is supposed to be easier in SQL2012)

Comment: I'm stuck with SQL2005 and I don't see how I can pass the resultset of a query on to another package...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a sub package for the Loop logic as @Bill mentioned, and the way to 'pass the resultset of a query on to another package' is as below (use SSIS 2012 as the example, I did the similar work SSIS 2005, so you only need to change the c# code to vb.net)

1. In your parent package, create a variable to hold the name of the *resultSet* variable in the parent package:
   [image]
2. In your sub package, create a string variable *parentResultSetName*:
   [image]
3. In your sub package, add a package configuration to mapping the *parentResultSetName* to the parent package variable *resultSetVariableName*:
   [image]
4. Now, we can read the *resultSet* variable by the name in the script task of sub package:

   ```
   public void Main()
   {
       // TODO: Add your code here

       var dsName = Dts.Variables["parentResultSetName"].Value.ToString();
       Variables variables = null;

       DataSet resultSet = null;

       Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead(dsName);
       Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref variables);

       try
       {
           resultSet = variables[dsName].Value as DataSet;

           if (resultSet != null)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Sub package get: " + resultSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
           }

           Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "", e.Message, "", 0);
       }
   }
   ```
5. Here is the result:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Just place both your queries from "select batch logins" tasks to recordset and make another foreach loop over that recordset, executing those two queries from a variable. 
I can see that in your second foreach loop there are some additional tasks, so you'll have incorporate them to "Select all batch logins" task somehow, or make constraints that'd match in both loops.

Comment: The db-schema and even the stored procedures which return the data I work with are outside of my control.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to add an 'action' column to your 'batches' table. (or add an outrigger table). Work out *beforehand* what you want to do to the records. Then just delete the records and files once.

It looks like you are doing [RBAR](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CD4QFjAB&url=https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/&ei=FWA-UZu8O6re7AbB04HACg&usg=AFQjCNH4pWw5Fu-nwX1sYe7Kfpma5vzUBg&sig2=uqF8e3rD3LMLbkZWuW_PnA&bvm=bv.43287494,d.d2k) operations here.

So for example you run a couple of UPDATE statements against your tables that leave the tables in a state where each record is flagged for deletion or not.

Then after that you go through the loop and delete based off what is in the table.

It would make your package a lot simpler. and you can incorporate some 'commit' logic that makes sure a record and file are always deleted at the same time.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution which does not require any change outside of what's defined in SSIS.

Comment: So you need to research passing your recordset variable to a child package. What have you tried so far? Does this help: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/variables-ssis-dynamic-parent-to-child